# Show loader in Meteor reactive-table until data is ready for client

Tags: meteor, loader, reactive

I have used meteor reactive-table https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table for show data listing. How to use `ready: ReactiveVar(Boolean)` option in settings code?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your reactive table is showing data from a subscription. You would then have the `ready()` state of that subscription inform the reactive-table.

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  this.mySub = Meteor.subscribe('mySubscription');
});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  settings: function () {
    return {
      collection: collection,
      rowsPerPage: 10,
      showFilter: true,
      fields: ['name', 'location', 'year'],
      ready: this.mySub.ready(),
    };
  }
});
```

Note that this requires you use [ReactiveTable.publish](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table#server-side-pagination-and-filtering-beta) on the server.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have solved loader issue using reactiveVar

Answer (score 0):

Using **ReactiveVar** we can get subscription is ready or not.

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  this.isSubscriptionReady = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  settings: function () {
    return {
      collection: collection,
      rowsPerPage: 10,
      showFilter: true,
      fields: ['name', 'location', 'year'],
      ready: Template.instance().isSubscriptionReady
    };
  },
  isSubscriptionReady: function () {
     return Template.instance().isSubscriptionReady.get();
  }
});
```